# table function in R

Tags: r

I'm using the table function in R to create a table of two of my variables in R.
I have a data.frame like this

```
mytable

V1    V2    V3
1     a     c
2     c     d
3     b     b
4     d     a
5     d     c
```

when I use the table function table(mytable$V2, mytable$V3) I get the following

```
     a    b    c    d
a    0    0    1    0
b    0    1    0    0 
c    0    0    0    1
d    1    0    1    0
```

Now I actually want to treat situations 'a-b' the same as 'b-a'. Or 'b-c' the same as 'c-b'. Therefore I want to have a table where everything above the diagonal is empty. He needs to add the values from above the diagonal to the values below the diagonal. How can I do this in R?

And furthermore I want this table to be represented as a heatmap, which I normally do with ggplot2. But I don't know if this also works for a table that will have empty values above the diagonal.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the manual way of fixing it:

```
tab <- table(DF[,2:3])
tab[lower.tri(tab)] <- tab[lower.tri(tab)] + tab[upper.tri(tab)]
tab[upper.tri(tab)] <- NA
#  V3
#V2   a  b  c  d
#  a  0         
#  b  0  1      
#  c  1  0  0   
#  d  1  0  2  0
```

Comment: My real dataset is much bigger. The problem now is that in my real data I'm missing the 'e' in V2, while in V3 every letter is present. So this means that the resulting table is not completely symmetric. Therefore your solution is not working in my case.

Comment: Make the columns `factor`s with the same `levels`.